# How to make Many2many field editable in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo

I have many2many field and displaying on a form.
How can make this Many2many field editable ?

Comment: By editable you mean your not seeing additem button i guess

Comment: By default any field not computed is editable, is your field computed ?

Comment: By default all fields are editable as said by @khelilimiliana

Answer (score 1):

In your tree definition of `many2many` add `<tree create='1'>`.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

if your Many2many field is added as tree, you have to add editable="bottom" flag to the tree definition.

```
<field name="many2many_field_name">
    <tree editable="bottom" edit="True" create="True">.....
```

editable property can be set to either `top` or `bottom`.